# Lightweight feature-rich alternatives to OpenOffice and LibreOffice

Tags: software-rec, pdf, openoffice, libreoffice

I really like LibreOffice however I'm having issues with it freezing up and I can't seem to start a new instance of the writer on multiple desktops (I'm using dwm and want several documents open).

For this reason, I need a writer application (don't use spreadsheets or presentations that much) that has all the features of LibreOffice but can be launched independently of other instances.

The features I require the most would be:

- Rich text editing (bold/italics/fonts/font sizes/etc)
- Ability to add headers and footers to pages
- Ability to add formulas to pages (I'm sure this can be accomplished with a LaTeX plugin of some sort)
- Portrait/Landscape view
- Split text into columns
- Export to pdf (not essential but makes it easier if its integrated)

I've tried [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net) without much success. Any ideas? Maybe my problem with LibreOffice can be fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend trying to fix the LibreOffice problem, but if that doesn't work, have you heard of [Abiword](http://www.abisource.com/)?  It's older than the OpenOffice.org project and is similar to MS Word (pre-ribbon versions) or Writer from the LibreOffice suite.

Another idea, if you are familiar with LaTeX, is to try one of those near- (or not quite so near-) WYSIWYG editors like [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) (KDE), [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) (Qt dependencies), or [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) (Qt).

**Caveat:** I have not used any of the above pieces of software because LibreOffice and straight `pdflatex` have been enough for everything I've needed to do so far.

Comment: I've started using Texmaker and absolutely love it!

Answer (score 1):

[Texmacs](http://www.texmacs.org/) will do 2 columns, and is relatively lightweight and provides rich text:

[image]

That seems to imply that you don't get three or more columns, but... that is the cost of asking for "lightweight".

Mind you, I just use LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be able to start a new instance of Writer if you create a separate user. Also, try KWord.